# Get a sharable link in python for drive files

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to get a sharable link so that a sign in is not required when downloading a  google drive file. I can get this link from google drive UI but I want to get it from my python code. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little too broad, therefore my answer will help you in a general way. Using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%22your-file-id%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22webViewLink%22%7D) in the Files: get endpoint and specifying in the ***fields*** request parameter `webViewLink` you will obtain a link, which you can use, but noticed this will only work if the user, who is requesting the file, has already at minimum read permissions to that file.

Translating the previous API call to Python code, it will look like this:

```py
# Don't forget to build your Drive service instance 
sharable_link = service.files()\
        .get(fileId="your-file-id", fields="webViewLink")\
        .execute()
print(sharable_link.get("webViewLink"))
```